# Flutter Firebase Google Sign In not working. Stops after account selection

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-signin

I am currently trying to implement google sign in and authentication within my app. I have set up a project and created an app in Firebase, put the google-services.json in the application, added the necessary plugin to build.gradle, and set the SHA-1 key in firebase. Email authentication is working great, however google authentication is causing problems.

All authentication is done from an 'authentication' package I have created. It contains an authentication page and performs all auth logic. The 'main' flutter app which is run, imports this package for use. This 'main' project's build.gradle files contain the additions for the google services plugin (`com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2`). Once the 'main' project is run it checks if the user is currently logged in. If not it passes control to the 'authentication' package to display an auth screen and handle the login.

The problem occurs after selecting the google account I want to login with. Once the account is selected, the account selection dialog closes and nothing happens after that. The user is not authenticated (confirmed in Firebase), no exceptions are thrown, and the try-catch surrounding everything does not catch any exceptions. It seems as if all execution of the function halts. I can still move through the app, but the sign in method never finishes execution.

You can see the sign in method below. After the execution of the line `final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();` execution does not continue for some reason.

```
///
  Future<String> _signUpWithGoogle() async {
    bool isLoggedIn = await _firebaseAuth.isLoggedIn();
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
      googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
      final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount =
          await googleSignIn.signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
          await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
        accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
        idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
      );

      final AuthResult authResult =
          await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;

      assert(!user.isAnonymous);
      assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

      final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _firebaseAuth.getUser();
      assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

      return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';
    } else {
      FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.getUser();
      return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';
    }
  }
```

I would think a PlatformException should come back if something went wrong, but no exceptions are returned the first time. If I trigger the google sign in method again I recieve a PlatformException that says:

```
PlatformException(error, Concurrent operations detected: signIn, signIn, null)
```

Below you can also find the dependencies for the 'main' app and the 'authentication' package:

'main' app dependencies

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  permission:
  intl_translation:
  flutter_svg:
  sqflite:
  path:
  path_provider:
  uuid:
  qr_flutter:
  vibration:
  reflectable:
  provider:
  launcher_module:
    path: ../modules/launcher_module
  individual:
    path: ../modules/individual
  common:
    path: ../packages/common
  persistence:
    path: ../packages/persistence
  resources:
    path: ../packages/resources
  authentication:
    path: ../packages/authentication
  screen:
  flutter_screen_scaler: ^0.0.1
  page_indicator:
  toast: ^0.1.5
  rxbus: ^0.0.2
  shared_preferences:
```

'authentication' package dependencies

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.3+1
  google_sign_in: ^4.1.1
  flutter_facebook_login:
  shared_preferences:
  common: 
    path: "../common"
  toast: ^0.1.5
```

I have also tried moving all authentication logic into the main app and removed the reference to the 'authentication' package. However, the same thing still happens.

Is there something I am doing wrong or missing in all of this?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code above. I have nearly identical code that works, with the same version of the `google_sign_in` plugin. What I would do is debug the native code of the plugin in order to figure out where it gets stuck and then understand why that happens. Given the `PlatformException` that you mentioned, and after having a quick glance at the plugin's code, it definitely gets stuck somewhere between the `onActivityResult` callback when selecting the account to sign in with, and sending the result back to Flutter.

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion led me right to the issue. In the project's own native code, in an activity, I forgot to add `super.onActivityResult()`. So the `onActivityResult` in the plugin was never getting hit. Fixed that and it works great now.

Comment: I am running into this same issue, could you provide a code example of how you fixed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just to turn my previous comment into an official answer:

**Initial comment:**

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code above. I have nearly identical code that works, with the same version of the `google_sign_in plugin`. What I would do is debug the native code of the plugin in order to figure out where it gets stuck and then understand why that happens. Given the `PlatformException` that you mentioned, and after having a quick glance at the plugin's code, it definitely gets stuck somewhere between the `onActivityResult` callback when selecting the account to sign in with, and sending the result back to Flutter.

**After author replied:**

It turns out that the author had customized the app's starting Activity such that `onActivityResult` was no longer calling `super.onActivityResult`, which prevented the `google_sign_in` plugin from sending data from the native side back to the Flutter side.

The same mechanism is used whenever an `Intent` that is meant to return data is launched, such as requesting permissions, or taking a photo with a different app.

Comment: How to do that , please explain

Comment: Kudo to this guy. This is an self inflicting error that took me forever to figure out since no error message is returned (as intended)

Comment: super.onActivityResult was missing. Thanks a ton.

Comment: why did you explain about that in detail? @Paraveen-Aanand requested this already. Here is open-community. Please explain about that.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue - it looks like we're working from the same tutorial (I'm new at this too).
For me, the problem was the SHA certificate fingerprints in Firebase - if you haven't set them up then the sign in simply won't do anything. In the terminals tab I could see that sign-in simply cancels itself.

To fix the issue I did this:

- Set up my Key file (keystore - yes initially I forgot to do this!)
- Added my keystore file to the Android folder
- Created a key.properties file in Android/app/ folder
- Added my dependencies for the file in Android/app/build.gradle
- From terminal window run android/gradlew.bat
- Then in the same window run "gradlew signingReport"  - this will give you SHA1 and SHA256 keys
- Go in to firebase console, project, settings, general, andorid apps and enter the SHA certificate fingerprints that grade gave you.

Then rebuild the app and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I've added debugging sha1 key to firebase before 4 months,and now i tried to do some changes,but cannot signedIn.In the meantime i changed my laptop OS,so my **debugging sha1 key is changed automatically.**

Also if you uninstall Android studio and its data, but keeping only vscode, then also it happens, now you need to re generate your debugging key and add it to firebase.

`now the required step is to create new debugging key add it to firebase.`

*Note: this is will not be primary cause for many cases,but give it a try*

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have forgot to add dependency at project-level build.gradle and app-level.
When adding android and ios app through Firebase CLI.

[image]

**Make Sure to add this at project-level build.gradle**

[image]

**and At app-level build.gradle**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was I didn't have Google sign-in method enabled in Firebase. I was getting the popup allowing me to select my google account and I could see using print statements that I was getting stuck in:

```
final googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
```

and my app would seemingly stop working after I clicked on my username. Everything started working when I enabled Google sign-in on Firebase.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by following steps :

**1. Generate SHA-1 Fingerprint :**

**2. Update Firebase Console:**

Here is my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78007164/6109034

Answer (score -1):

**auth.dart**

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

abstract class BaseAuth {

  Future<String> signInWithGoogle();

//optional if you need to store user data
  String name = "User";
  String email = "Demo";
  String imageUrl = "https://celebritypets.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Adriana-Lima.jpg";


}
enum authProblems { UserNotFound, PasswordNotValid, NetworkError }

class Auth implements BaseAuth {

final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  Future<String> signInWithGoogle() async {


  final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
      await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );

  final AuthResult authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;

  // Checking if email and name is null
  assert(user.email != null);
  assert(user.displayName != null);
  assert(user.photoUrl != null);

  name = user.displayName;
  email = user.email;
  imageUrl = user.photoUrl;


  // Only taking the first part of the name, i.e., First Name
  if (name.contains(" ")) {
    name = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(" "));
  }

  assert(!user.isAnonymous);
  assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

  final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
  assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

  return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';
}
```

**authprovider.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:multitask_flutter/auth.dart';

class AuthProvider extends InheritedWidget {

  AuthProvider({Key key,Widget child, this.auth}) : super(key: key,child: child);
  final BaseAuth auth;


  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) => true;

  static AuthProvider of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<AuthProvider>();
  }

}
```

**loginpage.dart**

```
import 'package:appname_flutter/authprovider.dart';
//just call this... when user click on button...

var auth = AuthProvider.of(context).auth;
auth.handleSignIn();
```

And You Done...

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hope what helps?