# Flutter: Google sign-in method, unable to open the select email account after clicking sign in with google

Tags: android, flutter, google-signin

I am trying to create a button to sign in using a google account in Flutter. I am using the google sign-in package for authenticating through Firebase. I have created fingerprints in firebase with SHA values and imported the google JSON file in android/app.

I am unable to get the box where the user selects the google account they want to log in with.

The error I'm getting is: "Could not find the correct Provider above this MyApp Widget"

My main file looks like this:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: GoogleSignInProvider(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text("Check"),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Colors.black, onPrimary: Colors.blue),
              child: const Text("Sign in with Google"),
              onPressed: () {
                final provider =
                    Provider.of<GoogleSignInProvider>(context, listen: false);
                provider.googleLogin();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and my Google sign in file looks like this:

```
class GoogleSignInProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  GoogleSignInAccount? _user;
  GoogleSignInAccount get user => _user!;

  Future googleLogin() async {
    final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    if (googleUser == null) return;
    _user = googleUser;

    final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by following steps :

**1. Generate SHA-1 Fingerprint :**

open terminal under your project directory and run this

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

**2. Update Firebase Console:**

```
- in your firebase project 'Add fingerprint' and update this key
```

Answer (score -2):

use this when calling method sign out

`googleSignin.disconnect();`

You can use these 2 together as well

```
await authService.logout();
  await googleSignin.disconnect();
```