# Firebase: Google Sign In failed - nothing happens when choosing your account

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-signin

I am facing an issue with the Google SignIn using Firebase.
I followed all the mentioned steps ([from here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin)) when it comes to the implementations, but I changed the code, since the one provided wasn't very clear.
My app is connected to Firebase and the email authentication works without any issues. However, when I open the app and click on "sign in" with google, I get to choose an account, and then nothing happens.
I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59790087/flutter-firebase-google-sign-in-not-working-stops-after-account-selection), but since my app is in Android Studio (Kotlin), I don't really understand the code and the explanation from Flutter.

As you can see below, the Google Sign In option is activated:

[image]

Here is the code from the Login activity:
('client_id' is the Web Client Id that I took from the SDK configuration from Firebase)

```
@SuppressLint("CheckResult")
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityLoginBinding
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)


//  Auth
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

//  Config google sign in
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

//  Click

        binding.googleBtn.setOnClickListener {
            signInGoogle()
        }
    }

    private fun signInGoogle(){
        val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
        launcher.launch(signInIntent)
    }

    private val launcher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){
        result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result.data)
                handleResults(task)
            }
    }

    private fun handleResults(task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
        if (task.isSuccessful){
            val account: GoogleSignInAccount? = task.result
            if (account != null){
                updateUI(account)
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, task.exception.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    }

    private fun updateUI(account: GoogleSignInAccount) {
        val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.idToken, null)
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful){
                val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("email", account.email)
                intent.putExtra("name", account.displayName)
                startActivity(intent)
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, it.exception.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, from the HomeActivity (after signing in, you should go to this activity):

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityHomeBinding
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        val email = intent.getStringExtra("email")
        val displayName = intent.getStringExtra("name")

        binding.textView.text = email + "\n" + displayName
```

plugins & dependencies build.gradle (Module):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.0.7'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.19"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.0.0"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.2')

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0'
}
```

build.gradle (Project):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
}


plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I don't understand what I did wrong, when I click on debug, I get something like this:

[image]

Any idea or thought on this would be very useful and appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300** (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.  Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to configure your project in Google API Console first. You have to add the package and SHA1 signature of your build.

Check this https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-started#api-console

or https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#configure_a_project

Here is the instruction on how to get SHA1 https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

[image]